# Not able to pass PHP array to jquery: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, json

Here is what I have in PHP:

```
$arrayresults = array();
while($popularbrushesrow = mysql_fetch_array($popularBrushes)){

$arrayresults[]  = '<a href="brushdescription.php?id='.$popularbrushesrow['bd_brushid'].'"><img class="slideImg" alt="'.$popularbrushesrow['bd_brushname'].'" title="'. $popularbrushesrow['bd_brushname'].'" src="'.$popularbrushesrow['bd_imagefilepath'].'"  /></a>';

}

echo json_encode($arrayresults);
```

Now, jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'getDataForSlide.php',
    data:"limit="+limit+"&required="+required,
    dataType:"json",
    cache:true,
        success: function(result){
     var arrayFromPHP = JSON.parse(result);
     alert(arrayFromPHP);
  }
})
```

Could someone please help me out. Whats the correct way to form an array in JSON?

Comment: Are you actually returning anything?  is that data actually appending to the GET?

Comment: If you specify the datatype, jQuery will already parse the JSON for you.

Comment: do a `console.log(result)` and see what comes through. Probably you've got a shutdown script or something outputting non-json data AFTER your json_encode call, leading to the error. e.g. an html footer or something.

Comment: what do you get when you consol.log(result);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely to be this line:

```
var arrayFromPHP = JSON.parse(result);
```

Because you've specified `dataType: 'json'` in the `ajax` options, jQuery has *already* done the parsing for you. So doing it a second time starts out by doing `toString` on the array, which does a `join`, which results in invalid JSON.

Simply use `result` directly.

For example, suppose you have this JSON:

```
[
    "<a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">Stack Overflow</a>",
    "<a href=\"http://google.com\">Google</a>"
]
```

Because jQuery has already done `JSON.parse` on it, `result` is an actual array. So if you then pass it into `JSON.parse`, the first thing *that* does is `toString`, which gives you this:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>,<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

...which is not, of course, valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify your jquery....like this...

```
$.getJSON("getDataForSlide.php", { limit: limit, required: required}, function(json) {
console.log(json);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use

```
jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```

And don't forget to use die(); or exit(); on php side after you echo your results, since it's a ajax call. This information can be found here: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: I didnt mark it..... :) but it could be because he is using json as a datatype, so the parse will already be handled for him